# TCP Hole Punching works using Java sockets and not with Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, hole-punching

I read the paper on TCP hole punching available [here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/p2pnat.pdf).

In order to do this one has to bind the sockets which are used for making TCP connections to a remote host and that which the local host uses to listen for connections to the same port. I have been able to do this in Java but cannot in Python even when the SO_REUSEADDR flag is set for the given sockets. Can someone explain to me why? Is it because Python is in inherently single-threaded?

Comment: not really a java question,re-tag, go ahead

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without more information, preferably some code.

Comment: I know nobody on the planet who has successfully done a TCP hole punching. This should be interesting answer column

Comment: @Aniket, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching

Comment: @cobie I know what hole punching is and how it works. I just said I haven't seen anyone punch a hole with TCP packets.

Comment: Why not, instead, use UPnP? @cobie

Answer (score 5):

From far as I tested/studied TCP Hole Punching is not a viable technique that will work in every situation.
First, what TCP Hole Punching does is not well supported by NATs and their behavior is unpredictable.

In resume it relies on sending a TCP SYN packet and recieving TCP SYN packet (when in a normal conversation you would respond with SYN+ACK) so that the NAT would open a connection between the two hosts. Some NATs may open this connection while others dont.
The best way I know to acomplish **NAT Traversal** is to use UDP. Since UDP is not connection oriented, you can start sending packet and reciving so the NAT will think one packet is a reply form the other.

See
[UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Also, to make UDP as reliable as TCP you can use an implementation of TCP over UDP.

See [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/)

I am sorry I didnt answer your question, but why in Java worked and why in Python did not, is hard to know, it has something to do with virtual machines implementation and system calls or even the NAT you are using.

Comment: From my experience - use UDP and add some reliability on top of it. Even with UDP - it will not work in every situation (read about symmetric NAT), depends on how router manages the port mappings. If it is not predictable you can not traverse. However - you will be ok with 99% of the routers if you take care of all scenarios where it is possible. Also, you can tunnel TCP over UDP.

Comment: thank you, I didn´t know about the symmetric NAT. Is there no way to overcome this ?

Comment: This article explores the possibilities in details: http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-takeda-symmetric-nat-traversal-00.txt